# Apt update fail and keep connecting to an weird IP

Tags: networking, apt, dns, ip

It's weird that no mater I update or crawl anything from web. There is always a connection timeout error.

when update

```
kevin@KevinChen:/etc/apt/apt.conf.d$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for kevin: 
0% [Waiting for headers] [Connecting to 184.178.217.66 
(184.178.217.66)] [Conne
```

it keeps connecting to the ip as above and fail at last.

when crawl a website

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/kevin/Documents/Python/spider_caoliu2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/kevin/Documents/Python/spider_caoliu2.py", line 21, in <module>
     c.perform() pycurl.error: (7, 'Failed to connect to 
184.178.217.66 port 3128: Connection timed out')
```

the weird connection come out again.

After a little looking up. I find there is a file `apt.conf` in `/etc/apt` may responsible for this issue that the file contains a connection as above. But the issue still happen after deleting the file.

Is there any chance that the DNS is to blame on?

Comment: Nothing in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*` should have hardwired IP addresses. What do you mean by "contains a connection"? The address you list appears to be someone's mobile device; definitely not an ubuntu server!

Comment: Thanks pal.    apt.conf  contains  Acquire::http::proxy "http://118.244.213.6:3128/";

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I know what happened. When you installed, the installation process asked you if you needed to use a proxy, and you probably said "yes". Now it thinks that that's your proxy for all time. Just remove that line and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. But I removed the file apt.conf yet the problem still happen.

Comment: I found a similar issue here but I cant fix by the same means. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42547119/apt-get-trying-to-connect-to-unknown-ip

Answer (score 1):

I only changed one thing to get it working. Added "nameserver 8.8.8.8" to /etc/resolve.conf